# How to 'Go LIVE' with UBER API?

Tags: api, uber-api

Ok, Let me explain in detail:

- We are using the UBER API for building a Messenger BOT, so users can book an UBER from the BOT ( [messenger.com/t/ghostinthebot](http://messenger.com/t/ghostinthebot) )
- Following are the 'Priviliges' we have enabled:
  [Click to view screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQYmn.png)
- We have added 5 developers to the UBER developer dashboard.
- Now when we try to Book a UBER via. the BOT > It goes to the screen where it asks LOGIN to UBER.
- On this screen, only the developers we have added in the dashboard are able to login. If someone else tries, it gives an error: { statusCode: 401, data: '{"error": "invalid_grant"}' }.

So, we were under the impression that maybe there is a GO LIVE procedure for it to work for all. But just got the response from UBER that there is no such thing as GO LIVE.

Comment: im not sure this question fits in the scope of stack overflow.

Comment: Echoing the earlier comment, this may not be appropriate for StackOverflow unless you provide more details, such as the actual call & response of getting the error. I see you also DM'd to @uberdevelopers. Our team will respond to you there and ask for more information.

Comment: Yes, will add the actual call / Response details as well...

Comment: Hi Folks. The issue was on using the Privileged Scopes. So, we would need to REQUEST FULL ACCESS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved I guess. The issue was on using the Privileged Scopes. So, we would need to REQUEST FULL ACCESS. Thanks!